# How to custom fake-db feature in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How to use fake-db feature (I'm using [this](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/interfaces.d.ts)) in angular that support the api with response like below.
For getting the list

```
// GET 'api/outlets'
{
  data: [
    {'id':1, 'name': 'Outlet 1', ... },
    {'id':2, 'name': 'Outlet 2', ... },
    {'id':3, 'name': 'Outlet 3', ... },
  ],
}
```

For getting the detail

```
// GET 'api/outlets/2'
{
  data: {
    'id':2, 
    'name': 'Outlet 2', 
    ... 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `json-server` for that. you just need to create fake json whatever you want in one json file and follow the steps just like mentioned here

https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: Will try it. Hope it can handle GET list that has format `{ data: Outlets[] }` and handle GET detail that has format `{ data: Outlet }`.

Comment: yeah it will support that but you need to create json like that... if my answer helps please up vote and accept it so other can also find this helpfull :) happy coding

Comment: Sorry, upvoted only. Using fake-db only is enough, there's such feature on it. No need json-server

Answer (score 0):

Found the config for in-http-memory. Set `dataEncapsulation` to `true`.

```
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
    InMemoryDataService, { 
        dataEncapsulation: true, 
        ...
    }
),
```